# Using jQuery to alter form value

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm wanting to find each instance of **".simple-product-tile"** on a page, then for each append part of the href (the product code at the end of the url) to the nearest forms value which is blank by default.

HTML:

```
<div class="simple-product-tile">

    <!-- I need the product code at the end of the href 'demo2xx' -->
    <a href="/demo-product-demo2xx"></a>
    <form action="/basket/addproduct" id="product-form" method="post">
        <div class="tbx tbx-quantity">

            <!-- Append above product code to the empty value -->
            <input id="productId" name="productId" value="" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <button class="btn-add-to-basket" title="Add to basket" type="submit">
            <span class="btn-cnt">Add to basket</span> 
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Using some very basic jQuery I can change each value to an example code '000000':

```
$(".simple-product-tile form input#productId").each(function() {
    $(this).val('000000');
});
```

How do I cut out 'demo2xx' from the closest href and turn it into a variable I can apply to the nearest value?

I assumed I could use .slice() to cut out the required string from href, but as the product codes are different lengths I no longer think this will work.

Comment: Dan try out my answer. It will work as you want.

Comment: You should have uniqie `id`s in your html. Using multiple `id="productId"` is invalid and will result in problems.

Comment: Thanks, it's not my HTML. I'm simply working with what I'm given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$(".simple-product-tile").each(function() {
    var url = $(this).find("a").attr("href");  // Taking HREF value.
    var lastItem = url.split("-").pop(-1);    // Taking last part of the string.
    $(this).find("#productId:first").val(lastItem);  // Assigning value to input.
});
```

Here I would advice to keep `productId` unique to the page. Because ID should be unique on a DOM. I would suggest to make it `class="productId"`. And change the jquery selector accordingly `.productId` instead of `#productId`.

Comment: That's spot on! Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help friend.Thank you too for Accepting and Up voting my answer.

Comment: `pop` does not accept a parameter. It simple returns and removes the last item of the array.